# android facebook login do not show pop up dialog

Tags: android, popup, facebook-login

I integrated my app with Facebook SDK successfully. But currently when the user presses the login button my app opens Login activity as follows:

[image: https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/851562_376550965784116_2050104420_n.png]

What I want is to open the login dialog as in below:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: please show your code. Thank you